# A word that implies hungry but all food tastes bad and unappealing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that implies *hungry but all food tastes bad and unappealing*

This is the scenario:

One of my characters is starving after being trapped in a POW camp for several weeks, but when he finally gets out, the horrible conditions in the camp have made all food taste grimy and gross, so he is hungry, but food makes him gag

Does that make sense?

Comment: My wife says pregnancy. She said smells were unusual.

Comment: @StuW so your saying I should write that the prisoner of the POW camp was feeling pregnant because they were hungry but food tasted bad?

Comment: Loss of appetite, perhaps?

Comment: I agree with @TinfoilHat, loss of appetite. But the scenario is unrealistic. Really hungry people eat anything that vaguely resembles food, even if it smells bad.

Comment: I don't think that is a realistic situation. Try going without food for a few days and see how _you_ feel.

Comment: Why are you looking for a single word? Why not expand on thee theme of his fears that food has permanently lost its appeal, will always be tainted by that experience? Make something of the fact that now he has food he needs to rediscover the joy in it?

Comment: @Spagirl True, I will keep that in mind

Comment: A doctor might say your character is suffering from "asitia," which means the loathing of food, but also the loss of appetite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoidant/restrictive food intake disorder (ARFID). If you have ARFID you will feel a very strong need to avoid food in general or certain foods because of their smell, taste or texture. The idea of eating can fill you with anxiety. ARFID does not tend to be connected to issues with body image – it is an anxiety about the process of eating itself.

[mind.org.uk](https://www.mind.org.uk/information-support/types-of-mental-health-problems/eating-problems/types-of-eating-disorders/)